# Prevent inherited TabControl to create TabPages

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am creating a custom `TabControl`

```
public class CtlTabs : System.Windows.Forms.TabControl
{
    ...
}
```

I can insert this inherited `CtlTabs` in Design Mode from the Toolbox window.

However, whenever I drag this within the form, it creates 2 `TabPages` by default. Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

I tried overriding `OnControlAdded()` without success.

```
    protected override void OnControlAdded(ControlEventArgs e)
    {
        // base.OnControlAdded(e);
    }
```

I also tried `CtlTabs.TabPages.Clear();` on HandleCreated/ControlAdded events.

**Additional Information:** For this inherited `TabControl` every `TabPage` is created dynamically on the fly, and it sets object data in `TabPage.Tag`. So these two initially created `TabPages` are useless.

Of course, the workaround for now is to add/drag in the control and delete the initial tabpages manually. I just wonder if there is a way I can prevent this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

New tab pages are created by designer. Any override in runtime code (the inherited TabControl) will not help. You need specify you own designer or "downgrade" from `TabControlDesigner` to `ControlDesigner`.

The downgrading is pretty simple:

```
[Designer("System.Windows.Forms.Design.ControlDesigner, System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a")]
public class MyTabControl : TabControl {
}
```